# Why does the query optimizer not optimize this statement

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I am testing an issue and trying to understand why the optimizer will not optimize a condition that would always evaluate false. This will probably have a very straightforward answer, however, it is Friday and I am feeling dense so here goes:

Take the three statements below:

```
 DECLARE @Field1 = 22
 DECLARE @Test BIT = 0

   SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE(MyField = @FieldID OR @Test=1)--1. SLOW
   SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE(MyField = @FieldID OR @Test=0)--2. FAST
   SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE(MyField = @FieldID OR 1=0)    --3. FAST
   SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE(MyField = @FieldID OR 0=0)    --4. FAST
```

Query 1 lags the other queries in execution time by around 30 seconds. 
Query 2,3,4 returns data in under 1 second regardless of @FieldID existing in the table.

Why does query 1 take 30 longer to execute than query 3? The value @Test can not be changed in the WHERE statement so it should be treated as a constant value as in query 3, I would think.

Comment: SQL Server does not sniff the values of variables or perform any optimisation taking into account their values unless you use “OPTION (RECOMPILE)”

In the case that you use a literal it can simplify the query at compile time to remove the redundant or condition. For the first two queries with the variable and 30 times different runtime performance what does the execution plan look like?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks, I new it had to be easy.

Comment: I don’t know why the difference in your case between 1 and 2 though. Can you show the plan?

Comment: It is simple, MyField (PK) is indexed, however, it still allocates 100% to a full table scan.

Comment: SELECT Cost : 0%<----Table Scan: Cost 100%

Comment: But 2 should get the same plan as 1 as the optimiser doesn’t know at compile time what the variable value is.

Comment: @MartinSmith I don’t know why the difference in case between 1 and 2 either.

Comment: Can you paste the XML for the actual (not estimated) execution plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ ?

Comment: Perhaps the optimizer knows that the statement evaluates to true and it will have to return all rows, as opposed to not knowing and having to compare the values of each record.

Comment: No it doesn’t know that at compile time. The statements are compiled before the variable is even assigned. The actual plan may have something that allows it to do something more efficient at runtime but you haven’t shown them...

Comment: So the table I am testing has upward of 95 million records. I will offload and isolate this weekend so I can post more. In a little QuickTest table with 50000 records, I was unable to duplicate what was explained above.

Comment: It may just be that the first query brought all pages into memory and queries 2 and 4 (which also need to read the whole table) benefitted from it

Comment: I was starting to think along similar lines as well :) Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @RossBush It's worth asking whether or not this is adhoc or within a sproc? If it's a sproc, then it's param sniffing 100% (as has already been determined), and I would recommend the local variable approach. It's backwards compatible and so effective, I use it by default on all sprocs. The legend Oskar Sommarskog has a wicked [article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) on the topic that all SQL devs and admins should read.